# Incorrect input value retrieved during bound event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am performing some filter operation based on input keyed into a text box in the following manner:

```
$("#search").on('change keyup', function () {
    var search = $.trim($(this).val());
    ...perform search based operation
});
```

The problem I am running into is that when input is entered quickly, the latest value retrieved with `.val()` is not always up to date. For example, when logging the value of the search variable to the console and searching for "jquery"; this is what is logged when entered rapidly:

> LOG: j
> LOG: j
> LOG: j
> LOG: j
> LOG: j
> LOG: j

Slowing down the keystrokes gives the correct result:

> LOG: j
> LOG: jq
> LOG: jqu
> LOG: jque
> LOG: jquer
> LOG: jquery

When I removed the search based operation from `.on` and just log keystrokes everything logs correctly. I believe this might be some type of timing issue but am not sure if this is something known that I am just unaware of. I am running this against IE9 / jQuery 1.9.1.  What could be the cause of the incorrect value?

UPDATE:
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bPuJ5/15/

[image]

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10818

Comment: I still have the same issue capturing only the keyup event.

Comment: try here http://jsfiddle.net/F52d4/.

Comment: try `on('input propertychange')`

Comment: @Zenith, I left this open for OP to change and generate the problem.

Comment: here is a fiddle showing my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/bPuJ5/15/  I simulate a long task in the event by populate the select options.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `keydown` instead of `keyup`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F52d4/2/)

Keyup triggers upon releasing a key. It seems that when you type fast or hold down a key the keyup event does not trigger until there are no more keys being held down.

If you don't want the function to trigger on every key press, you could implement a short delay or time elapsed since last keystroke check to see if to perform search.

Comment: I tried that in my fiddle as well. Same thing happens on keydown.